# Is std::byte in C++ 17 equivalent to byte in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5, c++17

I just noticed `std::byte` in the C++ 17.

I am asking this question because I use the code below to send byte array to C++ to play audio sound.

*C#*:

```
[DllImport ("AudioStreamer")]
public static extern void playSound (byte[] audioBytes);
```

*C++*:

```
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
extern "C" void EXPORT_API playSound(unsigned char* audioBytes)
```

---

With the new `byte` type in C++ 17, it looks like I *might* be able to do this now:

*C#*:

```
[DllImport ("AudioStreamer")]
public static extern void playSound (byte[] audioBytes);
```

*C++*:

```
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
extern "C" void EXPORT_API playSound(byte[] audioBytes)
```

I am not sure if this will even work because the compiler I use does not support `byte` in C++ 17 yet.

So, is `std::byte` in C++ 17 equivalent to `byte` in C#? Is there a reason to not use `std::byte` over `unsigned char*` ?

Comment: Worth a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143318/stdbyte-on-odd-platforms. It starts with odd platforms, but the answers cover all the basics.

Comment: C# **requires** that bytes are exactly 8 bits, but if you're interworking C++ and C#, you can safely assume that C++ too is using 8-bit bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte),

> Like the character types (char, unsigned char, signed char) `std::byte` can be used to access raw memory occupied by other objects.

This tells me that you can freely replace

```
unsigned char audioBytes[]
```

with

```
std::byte audioBytes[]
```

in a function header, and everything is going to work, provided that you plan to treat bytes as bytes, not as numeric objects.

Comment: Given Microsoft's record of bringing their compilers in compliance with C and C++ standards, the question of using `std::byte` for interoperability with C# will remain a purely theoretical topic for a considerable amount of time.

Comment: I will be treating bytes as bytes and this sounds promising. I will try my best to modify my code and test this on GCC compiler that supports byte and will update you today.

Answer (score 0):

`std::byte` is equivalent to both `unsigned char` and `char` in C++ in a sense that it is a type to represent 1 byte of raw memory.

If you used `unsigned char*` in your interface, you can easily replace it with `std::byte`.

In your C# code this will result in no changes at all, on the C++ side this will make your type system more strict (which is a good thing) due to the fact that you will not be able to treat your `std::byte`s as text characters or as small integers.

Of course this is C++17 feature which may or may not be properly supported by your compiler.